# How do I distinguish my variables so that Angular --prod --aot does not result in values being empty at runtime?

Tags: angular, typescript

When running my code locally in production, I receive the values I expect from my functions which pass in two parameters that will then be returned by the function.

However after running `ng build --prod --aot` the variable name changes from `name` to `t` for all functions which causes one to produce a result at return but the other function produces a blank return.

I've tried renaming the function parameters both in the function calls (on the Angular template) and inside of the component.ts file.

These are the functions that I originally wrote:

```js
    submitContact(name,email,subject,message){
      const callable = this.fun.httpsCallable('contactEmail')
      callable({
        name:name,
        email:email,
        subject:subject,
        message:message
      }).subscribe()
      console.log(name,email,subject,message)
      alert("Thanks for your message")
    }
    submitForm(fullname,emailaddress){
      const callable = this.fun.httpsCallable('genericEmail')
      callable({
        name:fullname,
        email:emailaddress
      }).subscribe()
      alert("Thanks for signing up!")
      console.log(fullname,emailaddress)

  }
```

This is the code that is produced once `ng build --prod --aot` is run

```
t.prototype.submitForm = function(t, e) {
                this.fun.httpsCallable("genericEmail")({
                    name: t,
                    email: e
                }).subscribe(),
                alert("Thanks for signing up!"),
                console.log(t, e)
            }

            t.prototype.submitContact = function(t, e, n, r) {
                this.fun.httpsCallable("contactEmail")({
                    name: t,
                    email: e,
                    subject: n,
                    message: r
                }).subscribe(),
                console.log(t, e, n, r),
                alert("Thanks for your message")
            }
```

I would expect that both functions would produce a result in the console however the only one that does is `submitcontact`

Also I receive this error message when `submitcontact` runs:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': An object could not be cloned.
    at Object.t.messageJumpContext (chrome-extension://elgalmkoelokbchhkhacckoklkejnhcd/build/content-script.js:24:9921)
    at chrome-extension://elgalmkoelokbchhkhacckoklkejnhcd/build/content-script.js:24:8583
```

But again, the result still displays and I'm not sure what to pinpoint that would get the result for both functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use

> ng build --prod -aot --optimization=false

That disables minification.